# How to make a bot respond to a certain message sent after the command?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that simulates a turn based battle, but i have no idea how to make a bot respond after i've sent the command. what i have tried for now is:

```
async def battle(ctx):
    keyword = (1,2,3)
    enemy1 = ('Skeleton', 'Goblin', 'Bandit',)
    enemy2 = ('Knight', 'Barbarian', 'Archer')
    enemy3 = ('Elf Mage', 'Dwarf Warrior', 'Orc Brute')
    enemy1hp = 50
    enemy1dmg = 25
    enemy2hp = 75
    enemy2dmg = 35
    enemy3hp = 100
    enemy3dmg = 25
    playerhp = 150
    playerdmg = random.randint(10, 40)
    await ctx.send('Pick a number between 1 and 3')
    enemypicked = ctx.content.lower()
    for keyword in enemypicked:
        if keyword == '1':
            opponent1 = random.choice(enemy1)
            await ctx.send(f'{opponent1}, {enemy1hp}HP')
```

What i am trying to do is make the user choose a number and dependant on a number the bot will choose which enemy will appear,but i get the following error:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'content'

and i am out of ideas on how to make it work. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your Exception, look into [ctx.message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context%20message#discord.ext.commands.Context.message).

You can then use ctx.message.content to get the content of the message.

Then to *wait_for* a response, look into https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for

Comment: Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem :)